# What types of expressions are evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c

What types of expressions are evaluated at compile time?

I had this problem because I was learning conditional compilation.
`#if` is followed by constant-expression in conditional compilation and constant-expression should be evaluated at compile time.
I want to learn what kind of expression can be constant-expression and can follow `#if`.

```
#if x>0 || defined(ABC) && defined(BCD)
```

Is this right, especially `x>0`?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. `#if` is a preprocessor directive and is evaluated before compilation.

Comment: This isn’t even a C expression evaluated at compile time – it’s a preprocessor expression. “Conditional compliation” gives a hint as to when it could possibly be evaluated.

Comment: It is legal if `x` is a preprocessor macro from a `#define`. It won't work if `x` is a variable because variable values aren't known until runtime.

Comment: @John Kugelman Does the computer calculate when it compiles?For example , is the 2>1 2==1,and 2&&0 already converted to 1 ,0 and 0 at compile time?I mistakenly thought that only the values which was defined would be replaced at compile time.

Comment: @Ry-: Preprocessing is a part of C, per the C standard, and preprocessor expressions are part of that.

Comment: @bolov: By “compile time”, OP includes preprocessing, which is a part of C per the C standard.

Comment: @zhm: Yes, compilers calculate while compiling. They must, to evaluate preprocessor expressions.

Comment: A constant-expression in an `#if` is a conditional-expression in the C grammar that cannot contain assignment, increment, decrement, function calls, or comma operators and has only operands that are integer or character constants, and a few other restrictions, but can contained `defined` operators.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Is if(a=1) right at the same time #if(a=1) is false. Is this because a is a variable and variable is not evaluated in compile time?And constants can't be assigned value.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil What the preprocessor expressions include?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247271/discussion-between-zhm-and-eric-postpischil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not trivial to write a complete and correct answer the question, since a lot of things are computed at compile-time in C. To answer, one would need to go rather deep into the C standard with lots of "language lawyer" terms used internally by it.

---

First there is the whole pre-processing part as described in *translation phases* (C17 5.1.1.2). Included in those pre-processing translation phases is for example the `#if` directive, which has the formal syntax like:

> `# if` *constant-expression* *new-line*

Where constant expression is another term for expressions that are always evaluated at compile-time. C defines such expressions in C17 6.6:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and
> accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.
>
> **Constraints**
> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.
>
> Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable
> values for its type.

It then categorizes constant expressions into the following types:

- *Integer constant expressions*

  > An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands
  > that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof`
  > expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating
  > constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.
- *Arithmetic constant expressions*

  Nearly identical definition as per above except it also allows floating point types. So an integer constant expression is also an arithmetic constant expression. (The *arithmetic types* in C are all integer and all floating point types.)
- *Address constants*

  > An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary `&` operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by the use of an expression of array or function type. The array-subscript `[]` and member-access `.` and `->` operators, the address `&` and indirection `*` unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be
  > accessed by use of these operators.
- Implementation-defined forms (compiler-specific language extensions).